# Remote Powershell parsing

Tags: windows, parsing, powershell

Im trying to retrieve a parsed list of different information regarding remote executables within a windows domain, permissions are take care of and the individual Powershell commands are working, my issue is outputting this recursive list on a file (putting all together properly):

My desired Output (*per computer*):

```
computer_name.csv # Filename

$application1Name.exe, $application1Version, $application1LastModifiedDateMMDDYY, $application1MD5HASH
$application2Name.exe, $application2Version, $application2LastModifiedDateMMDDYY, $application2MD5HASH
```

...

So far I have all the pieces:

```
#A way to recursive retrieve executables from a given remote path (Name + LastModified):
get-childitem \\192.168.X.X\C$\defaultPath\FoldersAndSubfoldersWithExecutables\ - Include *.exe -Recurse | ForEach-Object {$_.Name, $_.LastWriteTime} > C:\LOCALPATH\output.txt

#A way to retrieve the version info from remote executables (Version):
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("\\192.168.X.X\C$\defaultPath\application1.exe").FileVersion

#A way to retrieve the MD5 Hash from remote executable files (MD5HASH):
get-FileHash \\192.168.X.X\C$\defaultPath\application1.exe -Algorithm MD5 | ForEach-Object { $_.Hash }
```

My issue is building this script structure to accomodate the desired output listed above, I have a list of IP address to loop this script thru but Im having issues connecting the dots..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each operation you listed can be executed within the ForEach-Object loop, and a resultant csv string containing all the necessary data points can be built using string interpolation.

```
Get-ChildItem \\192.168.x.x\C$\defaultPath\FoldersAndSubfoldersWithExes\ -Include *.exe -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $Name = $_.Name
    $LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
    $Version =[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName).FileVersion
    $Hash = (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash

    "$Name, $Version, $LastWriteTime, $Hash"
} | Out-File computerName.csv
```